# Finding MIN MAX pairs from array

Tags: c++, sorting, search, binary-search

Given a sorted array of N integers, I need to find to all pairs with different indexes`(i!=j)`. I need the maximum `(a[j]+a[i]-1)` and minimum `(a[j]-a[i]+1)` out of all pairs with `(j>i)`. Numbers aren't unique but their pairing is allowed. Numbers can't pair with themselves.

What I'm doing right now :

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
    {
      MAX= max(MAX,a[j] + a[i] -1);
      MIN=min(MIN,a[j]-a[i]+1);
    }
}
```

This gives the time complexity of O(n^2). Is there a way to reduce it to O(nlogn) or even less ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the **max** you just need to add the elements at index n-1 and n-2, as the array is already sorted and the 2 biggest elements will be only at the end of the array. No other element in the array will be bigger than these and hence their sum will also be greater than the sum of any other elements.

```
MAX = a[n-1] + a[n-2] - 1;
```

**Time complexity** : O(1)

For finding the **min** , you should look for pivot in the array. I choose to start from a[0]. If space is not a constraint create another array of similar size and populate it with the delta values from your pivot.

```
int[] b = new int[n];
for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
{
  b[i] = a[i] - a[0];
}
```

Now the second array will have the delta values from your pivot. All you have to find is the indices of the Minimum and next-Minimum values of Array b. These 2 will be the closest values to each and hence their difference will also be the least.

**Time Complexity** : O(n) + O(n) = O(n)

**Space Complexity** : O(n) as a new array of same size has to be created.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get it now.